# CameraX: is it possible to use CameraX to access ToF (Time of Flight) sensor depth map?

Tags: java, android, android-camera2, android-camerax

I wonder if it is possible to use CameraX to access ToF (Time of Flight) sensor depth map.

Or should I use Camera2 ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vinit Modi, a Program Manager at Google, [writes](https://groups.google.com/a/android.com/g/camerax-developers/c/iI-O5tWxiZs/m/KlSAnp2dAQAJ) on Mar 6, 2020:

> Accessing depth data is currently only supported via camera2 API. Thanks!

Sorry to disappoint.

Comment: Thanks ! Would be great to have regular update from the Google team on this topic...

Comment: Apparently, you should subscribe to https://groups.google.com/a/android.com/g/camerax-developers/